# Understanding a sacrifice in Horace's carmen 1.5

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, roman-culture, horatius, religio

In Carmina 1, poem 5, Horace writes about an untrustworthy and seducing lady.
He ends the poem in:

> (...) Me tabula sacer
> votiva paries indicat uvida
> suspendisse potenti
> vestimenta maris deo.

Unscrambling the word order and translating, I read this as:

> Paries sacer tabula votiva indicat me suspendisse vestimenta uvida maris deo potenti.
>
> "The holy wall indicates by votive tablet that I have hung wet clothes to the powerful god of the sea."

What does this mean?
It sounds to me as if the writer made a customary sacrifice after surviving a shipwreck and surviving a shipwreck is getting away from that woman.
But this is fully guesswork on my part, as I am not familiar with any relevant sacrificial traditions.
It is just the only thing that came to mind that made some sense.

Is this how the message is usually read?
Am I missing something or reading too much into it?

Link: [Horatius, Carmina 1.](http://thelatinlibrary.com/horace/carm1.shtml#5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* how it is read.

But as for the “sacrificial” tradition, it is not a sacrifice but a votive offering in a tradition still practised in many parts of the Latin-speaking world. You promise God or a saint to make an offering to get you out of a sticky spot. The offering is of apposite form and nature.

For health troubles it might be an eye or an ear or a foot or whatever, made of silver perhaps. There are, here and there, chapels full of them. With surviving a storm it may be a model (ideally, made by you) of the ship that saved you. For shipwreck, a piece of the flotsam you came ashore on. Uvid vestments would be pushing it a bit, since they would take up a lot of room and soon go mouldy.

This tradition has not really changed since the time of Horace.